# I have an MFC legacy C++ that I wish to remotely debug, but the Deploy box is greyed out on the configuration. How do I enable it?

Tags: c++, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-2019

Following the steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2019

I have completed the steps up to where I must click the Deploy checkboxes in the Configuration Manager, but they are greyed out.

This is a legacy MFC 32 bit application.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The deploy buttons are only needed for apps (UWP, android).

Answer (score 0):

> I have completed the steps up to where I must click the Deploy
>   checkboxes in the Configuration Manager, but they are greyed out.

**1**.Please make sure you've set the `Debugger to launch` to `Remote Windows Debugger`.

[image]

**2**.And after my check, you should configure the `Deployment Directory` so that the project is deployable and the `Deploy Checkbox` is able to click.

[image]

**3**.Also, please check the Configuration and Platform you selected in `Project properties` and `Configuration Manager`, they should be corresponding to work.

**e.g:**

If we complete the settings in this way:

[image]

In Configuration Manager,only when we choose `Debug+X86`(Active Configuration and Active Platform) the Deploy checkbox is available, and if we change the X86 to X64, the checkbox would be grayed.

[image]

Hope it helps:)